# Camel-Jersey Integration

Tags: java, apache-camel, jersey-2.0

I have a requirement to use Jersey 2 as the Rest interface. I need to adapt this to an existing system which has used CXF to pass in SOAP requests. I know I should use CXF-RS but... it's not what the client wants.

I am auto-generating a WADL from a XML model and using that to autogenerate the resource classes (using CXF, but behind the scenes so to speak), so I really don't want to call a producer template from within the resource class.

So, I have thought that I could wrap the REST resource class in aspects that would capture the necessary information. Looking at it further I realise there are post-processing filters which would give me enough information to fire off a Camel producer template with the appropriate information taken from the resource method in question. That's where I am planning on heading.

And yet: I really want to do something a bit more stasifying and maintainable and reusable by creating a real Camel endpoint to do what I want. A consumer for now. I know this is possible. But my question is - where do I start? How do I map the Jax-RS resource classes to, say an exchange object and the parameters to headers. It seems as if it should be simple but I don't really understand the process by which one can as it were hijack the resource methods into the consumer method in a Camel component. Primarily I want to take advantage of the automatic JAXB conversion from xml to objects that it allows for.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [example](https://github.com/hoomanb1/fuse-examples/blob/master/camel-sql-xa-rest/fuse-spring-rest-messaging/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/spring-context.xml) and see if that helps, basically it exposes a REST endpoint and injects producer template into a bean that calls an activemq endpoint.