# How to integrate Apache Camel with Jersey 2.x?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, jersey-2.0

I have been trying to integrate **apache camel** with **Jersey 2.x**. Basically, i have some **rest api implements using Jersey**. For some special requirements, i am forced to use **camel routes for representing rest endpoints**.

I was searching tutorial, but could not find any.

But, I have found such as [Apache camel with Spring boot sample](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-spring-boot)->
and [spring-boot-sample-jersey](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey).
I was trying to combining those two. But I am not sure whether it is a right approach or not.

I have found **Apache Camel** could work well with **Apache CXF**. But my requirement is to integrate **Jersey with Apache Camel**.

Could you suggest any idea or tutorials for integrating **Jersey with Apache Camel**?

Notes: I have checked: [Camel-Jersey Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28276407/camel-jersey-integration), which did not fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

There is no first class camel-jersey component.

However you can call Camel from Jersey in the JAX-RS resource class.

There is a little example here, but its using CXF (not camel-cxf) as the example. But you could do similar with Jersey instead of CXF: https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter10/cxf-rest-camel